# Can you help me type postcode into the postcode form box on this URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to do a tutorial and learn Selenium in python however i cant seem to get Selenium to enter the postcode into the psotcode field/form box.=

I am using:

Python v3.9

Chrome v87

This is the URL i am practicing on:

https://www.currys.co.uk/app/checkout

And this is my current code:

```
# Selenium Tutorial #1

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

import time

# Open Chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Ste1337\Desktop\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")

# Open webpage
driver.get("https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/tv-and-home-entertainment/televisions/televisions/samsung-ue75tu7020kxxu-75-smart-4k-ultra-hd-hdr-led-tv-10213562-pdt.html")

# Click "Accept All Cookies" or ignore if no pop up
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler")))
    element.click()
except Exception:
    pass

# Wait 3 seconds
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

# Click "Add to Basket" or refresh page if out of stock
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "email-desktop")))
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.refresh()
except:
    button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.Button__StyledButton-bvTPUF.hZIOeU.Button-jyKNMA.GZkwS")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)

# Wait 3 seconds
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

# Click "Continue to Basket"
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.Button__StyledButton-bvTPUF.hZIOeU.Button-jyKNMA.sc-fzpjYC.gJohPa")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)

# Wait 3 seconds
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

# Click "Go to checkout"
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@data-component, 'Button')][contains(@type, 'button')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)

# Type in postcode
search=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@contains='Postcode Checker")))
search.send_keys("NG229NU")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Answer (score 0):

your locator is wrong for search , use:

```
search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@aria-label="Postcode Checker"]')))
```